# How Can One Javascript Enclosure Internal Function Call Another Internal Function

Tags: javascript, function, oop, call, internal

How can func2 call func1 within the same Javascript enclosure? Is this even possible?

```
var x = (function() {

    return {
        func1: function func1() {},
        func2: function func2() {
            var y = func1();  // Doesn't work! What does?
        }
    }

}());
```

Comment: Create `func1` before the `return` statement, then reference that (both in the object literal initialization that you're returning, and inside of `func2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `func1` before you return, then assign a reference to `func1` as a property of your return object.

```
var x = (function() {
    function func1() {}

    return {
        func1: func1,
        func2: function func2() {
            var y = func1();
        }
    }

}());
```

Comment: May I know what the code means? X is a function, that returns an object holding two functions?

Comment: @rps: Yes, `x` is an object containing `func1` and `func2`. `(function(){...}())` is an immediately invoked function expression that returns that object.

Comment: What is the purpose for fetching an object like this instead of just assigning it directly?

Comment: It allows code to be run in the scope of the anonymous function before returning the object, but the returned object can still refer to those "private" resources as needed. People sometimes use this pattern to simulate private and public members. Anything defined in the function body before the object returned is a private member, and anything returned as a parameter of the return object is public.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. That is exactly what I ended up doing, making the reference function private before the return literal. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = (function() {

return {
    func1: function func1() {},
    func2: function func2() {
        var y = this.func1();
    }
}

}());
```

Perhaps you are looking for something like that?